# Smartface webview doesn't plays youtube videos

Tags: smartface.io

Can anybody help me for this. I can't play any video on my app.

I created a web app it includes youtube videos. But android app doesn't play videos.

Answer (score 0):

Video object of Smartface App Studio can play directly video files.

If you assign youtube links it will not working if you don't know the exact video path.

But, I suggest you to use WebView component to show Youtube videos and pages.